# CakePHP Validation on input array that should be numeric and at least one is required

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

I want to create a rule which should validate from an input array to have atelast one required and that should be numeric. The input array is `goal_target[#]` where # is handled by back end with unique values.

I create this rule in Model. At-least one required am handling in controller and set the values in data set. Here is controller action:

```
//Removing initial zeros "0"
$this->request->data['goal_target'] = array_map(function($v) { return ltrim($v, '0'); }, $this->request->data['goal_target']);

//Removing empty values from input array
$this->request->data['goal_target'] = array_filter($this->request->data['goal_target']);

//Creating a data set for passing in model
$this->request->data['Goal']['targets'] = $this->request->data['goal_target'];
$this->Goal->set($this->request->data);

if(!$json_response && $this->Goal->AddValidate())
{
      //Adding goal
}
else
{
      $json_response['validations'] = $this->Goal->validationErrors;
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

In my modal:

```
public function AddValidate() {
        $validateAdd = array(
            'targets'=>array(
                'numeric' => array(
                    'rule' => 'numeric',
                    'allowEmpty' => true,
                    'message' => 'Numbers only'
                )
            )
        );
        $this->validate = $validateAdd;
        return $this->validates();
    }
```

Its not working properly even on numeric values. It always return message `Numbers only`. What wrong am doing please let me know. Also please tell if i can get the one required also in above rule.

Comment: Please show your code and also what error it returns

Comment: It return message 'Numbers only' I have validated the array for having numeric values only even then it showing 'Numbers only' message from validations.

Comment: Please update your question with your code so that we can see what you are doing.

Comment: I have added code in question. Please check.

Comment: whats your model? Have you added the validation rules in model file?

Comment: I've already mentioned my modal action in question.